# How to list the latest series with no gaps of a given clause?

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregation, gaps-and-islands

Given the following example table:

```
+-----------+
| Id | Name |  
+----+------+
| 1  | A    |
| 2  | B    |
| 3  | B    |
| 4  | C    |
| 5  | A    |
| 6  | B    |
| 7  | B    |
| 8  | B    |
| 9  | B    |
| 10 | X    |
+----+------+
```

I would like a query to get the following result:

```
+----+------+
| 6  | B    |
| 7  | B    |
| 8  | B    |
| 9  | B    |
+----+------+
```

The best query I could do was:

```
SELECT * FROM 
 (SELECT id, name, LEAD(id) OVER (ORDER BY id) t 
  FROM test WHERE name = 'B' ORDER BY id) 
WHERE ID <> t-1;
```

**[sqlfiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f4e86/2)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the length and where it starts:

```
select min(id), max(id)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by id) as seqnum_1
      from test t
     ) t
where name = 'B'
group by (seqnum - seqnum_1)
order by min(id) desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

You can join back to the table to get the original rows.

Another method using window functions to count the number of non-Bs *after* a given row . . . and then choose the first:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (order by nonbs_after asc) as grp
      from (select t.*, 
                   sum(case when name <> 'B' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by id desc) as nonbs_after
            from test t
           ) t
      where name = 'B'
     ) t
where grp = 1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=42f77c5ff6c6bf4993cdc04efddc88d5) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: @dellasavia . . . I added a db<>fiddle.